# What user to choose to install package with Composer on Ubuntu 22.04/Plesk Obsidian?

Tags: permissions, composer-php

On a virtual server (Ubuntu 22.04/Plesk Obsidian) I would like to install a composer project, but since it's [bad practice to run Composer as root/super user](https://getcomposer.org/root), I have to switch to a different user.

What user is best suited to do this job? Unfortunately, there is no www-data user which I have on my desktop linux.

Comment: Usually, you should not use Composer on any production server. Use a proper deployment instead, where Composer is run on any other machine, and solely the generated application files (including the vendor directory) are deployed

Comment: If you really want to avoid this: running Composer as root throws warnings, but it should work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Plesk you do not need to worry about this when you simply create a subscription and put your project into the subscription. Because Composer is also available in the subscription, and there everything is run using the subscription user account.